# Travel Routes in Java

Tags: java

I have very basic knowledge in Java. I tried below question and failing in some cases (I know that program is definitely incorrect). Can someone please help me, in solving this in Java?

Express the following table as a static structure, and write a function, find_routes(source, destination) that efficiently outputs all possible routes.

```
**Source**      **Destination**
Seattle         LA
LA              Florida
LA              Maine
Florida         Seattle
Seattle         Florida
```

*Ex:* The solution for find_routes('Seattle', 'Florida') should be [Seattle -> Florida, Seattle -> LA -> Florida]

I tried like below, but its failing when changed the destination:

```
public class FindPossibleRoutes {
    static boolean nextItr=true;
    public static void main(String rgs[])
{
        String[] source={"Seattle","LA","LA","Florida","Seattle"};
        String[] dest={"LA","Florida","Maine","Seattle","Florida"};
        find_routes("Seattle", "Florida",source,dest);
    }
    public static void find_routes(String s, String d, String[] sa, String[] da) {
        for(int i=0;i<sa.length;i++)
        {
        if(sa[i].equals(s)&&nextItr==true)
        {
            System.out.println(s+"-->"+da[i]);
            if(!(da[i].equals(d)))
            {
                find_routes(da[i],d,sa,da);
            }
            else {
                   nextItr=false;
                   break;
                }
        }   
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is failing? Please also give the wrong output and what you would expect.

Comment: For "find_routes("Seattle", "Florida",source,dest);", getting correct o/p..i.e., Seattle-->LA
LA-->Florida

Comment: But failing for "find_routes("Seattle", "Maine",source,dest);"..

Comment: Does "all possible routes" mean routes with loops as well? For instance Seattle -> Florida -> Seattle -> LA -> Maine.

Comment: It is really `finding path in graph` task. You can take a look here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/PathsInGraphs07.pdf or here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18603/finding-all-paths-on-undirected-graph

Comment: @t0mppa "all possible routes" for find_routes('Seattle', 'Florida') are:::: 1)Seattle --> Florida     2)Seattle --> LA --> Florida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your method already doesn't fit `find_routes(source, destination)` I assume it's okay to add another parameter `find_routes(source, destination, currentRoute)`.

First you have to define "static structures" is written in your question. Those would be something like:

```
private static String[] sourceArray      = {"Seattle", "LA",      "LA",    "Florida", "Seattle"};
private static String[] destinationArray = {"LA",      "Florida", "Maine", "Seattle", "Florida"};
```

Then of course this is a recursive problem. So you have to find the recursion anchor. Take a minute to think about it before you continue reading.

> The recursion anchor is obviously when the source is the same as the destination.

So after finding the recursion anchor you just have to add subsequent steps. Your thought about taking the corresponding destination as the new source is already the right way.
What you don't do is saving those subsequent steps.

For that I use the third parameter: currentRoute. It gets initialized as an empty list and always extended with the current node. If we end up at the recursion anchor, we can add our current route to the routes list.

If we are not at the recursion anchor we also have to check for cycles. To avoid those, we can just look in our currentRoute if the current node is already inside. Note that with huge datasets you now could still reach the stack limit, so some additional helpers would be needed (e.g. a cut off depth).

```
package sto;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PathFinding {
    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> routes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    private static String[] sourceArray      = {"Seattle", "LA",      "LA",    "Florida", "Seattle"};
    private static String[] destinationArray = {"LA",      "Florida", "Maine", "Seattle", "Florida"};

    public static void main(String rgs[])
    {
        find_routes("Seattle", "Maine", new ArrayList<String>());
        for(ArrayList<String> route : routes) {
            for(String node : route) {
                System.out.print(node + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void find_routes(String source, String destination, ArrayList<String> currentRoute) {
        // copy current route and add current node
        ArrayList<String> newRoute = new ArrayList<String>();
        newRoute.addAll(currentRoute);
        newRoute.add(source);
        // recursion anchor: source is destination, so route is finished and can be added to our routes
        if(source.equals(destination)) {
            routes.add(newRoute);
        } else {
            // check all possibilities for other routes
            for(int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; ++i) {
                if(source.equals(sourceArray[i])) {
                    // if node is already in our route: cycle, i.e. no solution or no optimal solution
                    if(!currentRoute.contains(source)) {
                        find_routes(destinationArray[i], destination, newRoute);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is definitely not the most efficient way, but it should give you a hint how to do it.